# Migrate java code from hbase 0.92 to 0.98.0-hadoop2

Tags: java, hbase

I hava some code, wrote with hbase 0.92:

```
/**
   * Writes the given scan into a Base64 encoded string.
   *
   * @param scan  The scan to write out.
   * @return The scan saved in a Base64 encoded string.
   * @throws IOException When writing the scan fails.
   */
  public static String convertScanToString(Scan scan) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(out);
    scan.write(dos);
    return Base64.encodeBytes(out.toByteArray());
  }

  /**
   * Converts the given Base64 string back into a Scan instance.
   *
   * @param base64  The scan details.
   * @return The newly created Scan instance.
   * @throws IOException When reading the scan instance fails.
   */
  static Scan convertStringToScan(String base64) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new  ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(base64));
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
    Scan scan = new Scan();
    scan.readFields(dis);
    return scan;
  }
```

I need to migrate this code to hbase0.98.0-hadoop2. There is no longer `write() readFields()` in Scan class. Can someone please help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hbase 0.92 the `Scan` class implemented the `Writable` interface which handled serialization. With Hbase 0.96 this type manual serialization was deprecated in favor of [Google's protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) (see issue [hbase-6477](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-6477)).

In order to serialize a `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan` with Hbase 0.96+ you need to convert it first to a `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos.Scan`. You can do this conversion from one to the other and reverse using the two overloaded `ProtobufUtil.toScan()` methods. ClientProtos.Scan has methods for serialization and deserialization, like `toByteArray` and `parseFrom`.

Using Protobuf your code could be rewritten to something like this (did not check results).

Write:

```
 public static String convertScanToString(Scan scan) throws IOException {
   return Base64.encodeBytes( ProtobufUtil.toScan(scan).toByteArray() );
 }
```

Read:

```
  static Scan convertStringToScan(String base64) throws IOException {
    return ProtobufUtil.toScan(ClientProtos.Scan.parseFrom(Base64.decode(base64)));
  }
```

The Protobuf serialization is not compatible with the old one. If you need to convert I would recommend just getting the old serialization code from the Scan class.