# Some methods are not availables in newer version of Hbase Scan class

Tags: java, hbase

I am new to hbase java api, and I am required to migrate old hbase, 0.94 codes to newer version of hbase 1.2.6. In this sense, I have realized that Scan.write() and Scan.readFields() methods are not available in the newer version.

I have look up older APIs and I have not seen these methods in any deprecated list. In hbase 0.98 these methods are not available. I cannot find a suitable way to replace them.

My code for scan.write is basically like this:

```
    Scan scan = new Scan();
    scan.addFamily(somefamily);
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(out);

    try
    {
        scan.write(dos);//this is not available
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        throw new IOException();
    }

    return Base64.encodeBytes(out.toByteArray());
```

And my code for scan.readfields is like this:

```
  ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(conf.get(SCAN)));
  DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
  scan = new Scan();
  scan.readFields(dis)
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is available [Migrate java code from hbase 0.92 to 0.98.0-hadoop2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30797065/migrate-java-code-from-hbase-0-92-to-0-98-0-hadoop2). Additionally, you need to add hbase-protocol library to access `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos.Scan` class.